# Openfaas Invoke async function with queue name

Tags: openfaas

Is there a way to give the queue-name with async openfaas function invocation ?

We have a openfaas function deployed which will be invoked by multiple providers.
The execution time of the function depends on some parameters given by the provider. We want to queue function invocation via a separate queue-name but keep only a single function as the invocations are sparse but spiky.

What is the way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the queue-name when deploying the function, but not when invoking it.

Reference :
https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/async/#multiple-queues